# Count number of occurrences of each unique element in a list in ansible

Tags: list, count, ansible

How can I count how many times is repeated each item in a list?

```
    ok: [] => {
        "list": [
            "5.8.3",
            "5.8.4",
            "5.8.4",
            "5.9.2",
            "5.9.2",
            "5.9.2"
        ]
    }
```

I want to print something like this:

```
    ok: [] => {
        "list_counter": [
            "5.8.3": 1
            "5.8.4": 2
            "5.9.2": 3
        ]
    }
```

I tryed something like this, but no success

```
    - set_fact:
        list_counter: '{{ item : 1 + item.get(unique_int[item],0) }}'
      loop: "{{ list }}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [*community.general.counter*](https://ansible.fontein.de/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_counting_elements_in_sequence.html#counting-elements-in-a-sequence) if you can install latest collection [Community.General](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/index.html#community-general)

```yaml
list_counter: "{{ list|community.general.counter }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
list_counter:
  5.8.3: 1
  5.8.4: 2
  5.9.2: 3
```

---

- If you're not able to install the collection take the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/community.general/main/plugins/filter/counter.py) and  create a custom filter plugin

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/my_counter.py 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright (c) 2021, Remy Keil <remy.keil@gmail.com>
# GNU General Public License v3.0+ (see COPYING or https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt)

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function)
__metaclass__ = type

from ansible.errors import AnsibleFilterError
from ansible.module_utils.common._collections_compat import Sequence
from collections import Counter


def my_counter(sequence):
    ''' Count elements in a sequence. Returns dict with count result. '''
    if not isinstance(sequence, Sequence):
        raise AnsibleFilterError('Argument for community.general.counter must be a sequence (string or list). %s is %s' %
                                 (sequence, type(sequence)))

    try:
        result = dict(Counter(sequence))
    except TypeError as e:
        raise AnsibleFilterError(
            "community.general.counter needs a sequence with hashable elements (int, float or str) - %s" % (e)
        )
    return result


class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible counter jinja2 filters '''

    def filters(self):
        filters = {
            'my_counter': my_counter,
        }

        return filters
```

Use it

```yaml
list_counter: "{{ list|my_counter }}"
```

---

- The declaration below gives the same result if you don't want to use collections or write a custom filter

```yaml
list_counter: "{{ dict(data|
                       unique|
                       zip(data|
                           json_query('[].{key:@, value: `1`}')|
                           groupby('key')|
                           map(attribute=1)|
                           map('map', attribute='value')|
                           map('sum')|list)) }}"
```

Comment: As I have read, for now is not an option for us because we are running ansible-core2.9. But we start to think about upgrading. Thank you Vladimir

Comment: Then take the [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/community.general/main/plugins/filter/counter.py) and create a [custom filter plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#plugin-guidelines).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install a collection or write a custom filter, you can do this using the `combine` filter:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    data: [
      "5.8.3",
      "5.8.4",
      "5.8.4",
      "5.9.2",
      "5.9.2",
      "5.9.2"
    ]

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        result_list: "{{ result_list | combine({item: result_list[item]|default(0) + 1}) }}"
      loop: "{{ data }}"
      vars:
        result_list: {}

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result_list }}"
```

The above playbook outputs:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.8.3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.8.4)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.8.4)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.9.2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.9.2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5.9.2)

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "5.8.3": 1,
        "5.8.4": 2,
        "5.9.2": 3
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```